# set auto increment size to 200001 and offset 10000

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am trying to set `auto_increment_increment = 200001` and `auto_increment_offset = 10000`
in my.cnf, but when i do `show variable like '%auto%'` it gives maximum increment value as 65535.

Then, I created a table with auto increment value as 200001, and inserted null value. When I do `select * from table;` it gives inappropriate result.

How can I set auto increment values to more 65535 and how can I receive correct results if i insert any values in table.

Comment: What data type is your column?

Comment: Give your `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`table\``. Maybe you've set the column to a `MEDIUMINT` or `TINYINT`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like auto_increment_increment is limited to 65535:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment